# preg_replace php to replace repeated characters

Tags: php, regex

So I have a list of values like that goes like this:

```
values: n,b,f,d,e,b,f,ff`
```

I want to use `preg_replace()` in order to remove the repeated characters from the list of values (it will be inserted to a MySQL table).  `b` and `f` are repeated. `ff` should not count as `f` because it's a different value.  I know that `\b \b` will be used for that.  I am not sure on how to take out the repeated b and f values as well as the `,` that precedes each value.

Comment: I think a regular expression is really the wrong method here.

Comment: What kind of list is it?

Comment: just regular text. not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for regex for this:

```
join(",", array_unique(split(",", $values)))
```

Answer (score 4):

If the list is in a string looking like the example above, a regex is overkill. This does it just as well;

```
  $value = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $value)));
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with other commenters that `preg_replace` is not the way to go; but, since you ask, you can write:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\b(\w+),(?=.*\b\1\b)/', '', $str);
```

That will remove all but the *last* instance of a given list-element.

Comment: Yeah, this is a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) if I ever smelled one. ;-)  Nice answer though.  (After you get rid of the `/g` flag, that is.)

Answer (score 2):

If this list you're dealing with is a simple string, a possible solution would be like this:

```
function removeDuplicates($str) {
    $arr = explode(',', $str);
    $arr = array_unique($arr);
    return implode(',', $arr);
}

$values = removeDuplicates('n,b,f,d,e,b,f,ff'); // n,b,f,d,e,ff
```

Comment: What is the reason behind downvoting this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "values: n,b,f,d,e,b,f,ff";
$arr = array();
preg_match("/(values: )([a-z,]+)/i", $str, $match);
$values = explode(",", $match[2]);
foreach($values AS $value){
     if(!$arr[$value]) $arr[$value] = true;
}
$return = $match[1];
foreach($arr AS $a){
    $return .= ($i++ >= 1 ? "," : "").$a;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, both Joachim Isaksson and JRL have significantly better answers.

Comment: thanks for your answer w regular expressions always good to learn!I m gonna go with JRL since its the shortest code.